# SOAP request exceptionjava.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: exception, soap, jboss

I am using EJB3 and hibernate running on jboss4.2.2.GA with jdk1.5

I have several soap web services and when I deploy EAR to the server, once the deployment is done and comes a request to my web services I get the following exception. BTW I can't figure out why but when I test it on local server there is not any error messages, wierd..

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance guys.

ERROR [org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.SOAPFaultHelperJAXWS] SOAP request exception

### java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.Envelope1_1Impl

[org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl] Error processing web service request

### org.jboss.ws.WSException: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.Message1_1Impl

[org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/myProject].[CatalogService]] Servlet.service() for servlet CatalogService threw exception

### java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.Message1_1Impl

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely that there is a different version of SAAJ in your web appliation. did you include the saaj*.jar files accidentally using the CXF web service facet? Delete them and you should be ok.